# reshape an element to an array after unwinding it

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection that looks like this

`{ name: 'ABC', metadata.tables: [ { name: 'table1' }] }`

Basically I want to query within the `metadata.tables` array to look for an elemMatch on the name of the table. I can do that using the aggregation pipeline by first unwinding the `metadata.tables` array and then doing the `$match` on table name. This works fine but now the `metadata.tables` becomes an object instead of an array. This is how the query looks like

```
db.source.aggregate([ 
 { "$unwind": "$metadata.tables" }, 
 { $match: { "metadata.tables.name": "table 1" } }
])
```

The returned document looks like this

```
{
 "_id": "......",
 "metadata": {
  "tables": {
  }
 }
}
```

Notice the tables are now an object instead of an array. I understand why unwind changes it to an object but how can I revert it back to an array with a single element in it (the matching table).

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just Perform a [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) with a [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/):

```js
db.source.aggregate([ 
 { "$unwind": "$metadata.tables" }, 
 { "$match": { "metadata.tables.name": "table 1" } },
 { "$group": {
     "_id": "$_id",
     "name": { "$first": "$name" },
     "tables": { "$push": "$metadata.tables" }
 }},
 { "$project": {
     "name": 1,
     "metadata": {
         "tables": "$tables"
     }
 }}
])
```

And optionally `$project` since aggregation accumulators cannot use an embedded field for output and you would need to rename much like as is shown.

Optionally you could use [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) if you knew you only had or just wanted a single element out of each "unwound" document:

```js
db.source.aggregate([ 
 { "$unwind": "$metadata.tables" }, 
 { "$match": { "metadata.tables.name": "table 1" } },
 { "$project": {
     "name": 1,
     "metadata": {
         "tables": {
             "$map": {
                 "input": ["A"],
                 "as": "el",
                 "in": "$metdata.tables"
             }
         }
     }
 }}
])
```

Which would essentially substitute the single element array provided to "input" with the value of the field.

Comment: For the first one, I think you meant `"tables": { "$push": "$metadata.tables" }`. That worked.Thanks

Comment: @adeelmahmood Yes I did. I really should proof read these things after posting. At least I said use `$push` beofre even though I somehow missed typing it in the actual statement.